# How to add a library or framework to XCode project at the runtime?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to add a static library `mylib.a` to Xcode at the runtime via buildscript. It needs to copy to project directory if needed as well.

I'll need something like following line of command to add just before the `xcodebuild` command in the buildscript. If anyone have done this before please share some example.

```
frameworkGroup = project.get_or_create_group('Frameworks')
    project.add_file(/Users/###/Desktop/mylib.a,
                     parent=frameworkGroup,
                     tree='SDKROOT',
                     weak=false)
```